# Elastic Search sort by boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to sort my list by true value in a field called **trusted**.

I have found that the sort option does not support boolean sorting.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should try term filter. Read the docs : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your issue well, I tried to do a test locally on ES version 7.8, and I ingested the following data in my index:

"content": "This is a test",
"trusted": true

"content": "This is a new test",
"trusted": true

"content": "This is not a test",
"trusted": false

Here is the mapping of the index:

```
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "content" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "trusted" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the query when `"order" : "desc"`:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "trusted": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The response:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "B-YleHQBsTCl1BZvrFdA",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is a test",
      "trusted" : true
    },
    "sort" : [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CeYleHQBsTCl1BZvtFdJ",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is a new test",
      "trusted" : true
    },
    "sort" : [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "DOYleHQBsTCl1BZvvVfl",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is not a test",
      "trusted" : false
    },
    "sort" : [
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

When `"order":"asc"`, the response is:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "DOYleHQBsTCl1BZvvVfl",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is not a test",
      "trusted" : false
    },
    "sort" : [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "B-YleHQBsTCl1BZvrFdA",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is a test",
      "trusted" : true
    },
    "sort" : [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "boolean-sorting",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CeYleHQBsTCl1BZvtFdJ",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "content" : "This is a new test",
      "trusted" : true
    },
    "sort" : [
      1
    ]
  }
]
```

Links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html

Please let me know If i wrongly answered, I will be glad to help.

Comment: I can confirm this is still an issue with ES 7.9. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
  "query"{},
  "sort": [
    {
      "my_boolean_feild": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```